# Гугл таблица заполняется некорректно через get запрос

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, imacros

Работая через iMcaros написал скрипт который отправляет данные в гугл таблицу get запросом. Но она заполняется только undefined.

```js
var macro;
for (var i=1;i<=1000;i+=2){
window.location = "https://www.сайт.ком/";
iimSet("i", i);
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+ "\n";
macro += "SET !errorignore yes"+ "\n";
macro += "SET !timeout_step 10"+ "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:\"spotlight-link\""+ "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:\"ss-navigateright\" EXTRACT=TXTALL"+ "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:\"ss-navigateright\" EXTRACT=TXTALL"+ "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=UL ATTR=CLASS:\"check-list\" EXTRACT=TXTALL"+ "\n";
var group = iimGetExtract(1);
var name = iimGetExtract(2);
var info = iimGetExtract(3);
iimPlay(macro) ;
var htp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
htp.open('GET', "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID скрипта/exec?col1=group&col2=name&col3=info", true);
htp.send();
}
```

скрипт гугл таблицы

```js
function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id таблицы");
  var n=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheet.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheet.getRange("B"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p1);
  sheet.getRange("C"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p2);
  sheet.getRange("D"+n).setValue(e.parameter.p3);
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(n-1);
}
```

Но на выходе
[image: то что имеем на выходе]

Подскажите что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Наверно уже поздно, но Вы неверно указали переменные.
Было:

```
htp.open('GET', "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID скрипта/exec?col1=group&col2=name&col3=info", true);
```

А надо:

```
htp.open('GET', "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID скрипта/exec?col1="+group+"&col2="+name+"&col3="+info, true);
```

Я уж не говорю, что вместо col1 ... надо указывать p1